# Best way to calculate cursory statistics from very large CSV

Tags: python, pandas, large-data, median, standard-deviation

I have some data in CSV format (16 billion rows, 170 columns).

I can extract each column using `cut` and load "just" one column from a file into Pandas using `pd.load_csv()`, but it is painfully slow and uses about 228GB of RAM while loading then settles back to 46GB for one of the columns while for some others tested my system with 256GB of RAM starts swapping and grinds to a halt.

Is there some way which is reasonably fast and requires less RAM to calculate standard stats like mean, median, standard deviation, and standard error on each column?

System(s) are all running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and I can install any package available through standard repos.

NOTE: Some columns have `u` for unknown/missing data while some just have nothing for the same but otherwise all the columns are either integers or floats.

Comment: You seem to be comfortable with the command line; I suggest you take a look at [`xsv`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv).

Comment: Additionally, `pandas` has support for [_lazy loading_](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) of files. Using that coupled with manually keeping track of your statistics of interest might be your best bet.

Comment: CSV are *clearly* not designed for performance and *really* not for files bigger than few GiB... Regarding your context, only specific low-level solutions can results in fast operations unless you can convert your big file to a better format (see Apache parquet which is at least a binary file format and design for quite big files -- not very efficient but still probably much better than csv). What is the input type of data stored in the CSV file? (eg. string, numbers, date, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answer, the comments have some good suggestions for not using CSV files.

In almost all cases, using something other than CSV is best, but sometimes (like in my case), it's what you have to work with. There are a couple of solutions that work reasonably well depending on factors.

I was unable to find a solution, so I just wrote my own.

Calculating the [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) and [Standard Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) (and [Confidence Intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)) does not require holding all variables in RAM; however, if you opt not to hold them in RAM you will have to read them twice. Once to calculate the [Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average), and the second for the sum of the difference between the mean and the values squared (sometimes referred to the [Mean Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_square)). With those two numbers and the number of variables you can calculate most of the most-common stats.

Example code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import math


def calc_some_stats(infile, col_idx):
    n, tot = 0, 0
    with open(infile, 'r') as fh:
        reader = csv.reader(fh)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                val = float(row[col_idx])
                n += 1
                tot += val
            except ValueError:
                # Ignore nulls, 'u', and 'nan'
                pass
            pass
        pass
    mean, sum_mean_sq = tot / n, 0
    with open(infile, 'r') as fh:
        reader = csv.reader(fh)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                val = float(row[col_idx])
                sum_mean_sq += (mean - val)**2
            except ValueError:
                pass
            pass
        pass
    variance = sum_mean_sq / n
    standard_deviation = math.sqrt(variance)
    standard_error = standard_deviation / math.sqrt(n)
    return n, mean, standard_deviation, standard_error


n, mean, stdev, sem = calc_some_stats("somefile.csv", 12)
```